# Can I use 'the' before the name of my college?

Tags: grammar

Should I say:

> "I am doing my graduation in the Dexter College"

or

> "I am doing my graduation in Dexter College".

Comment: "at Dexter college", usually. I'm not sure what you mean by "doing my graduation", though.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Hint: Do you expect to graduate ***from Dexter College***? Have you been in that course ***at the college*** this year? When did you begin attending ***Dexter College***? What course at ***the college*** interested you?

Comment: This is an interesting question. According to Ngrams results, one uses *The*  in 26.8% of references to "The Ohio State University**, but only in 6.4% of references to "University of Delaware". (The?) Dexter College does not return any Ngram results, unfortunately. For an overview of the general problem, see [Why there is “the” before some names but not others?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59271/why-there-is-the-before-some-names-but-not-others)

Comment: What does 'doing my graduation' mean?

Comment: There is no general answer. It depends on whatever the specific institution is.

Comment: Also see *[Use of definite article before phrases like Heathrow Airport, Hyde Park, Waterloo Station, Edgware Road and Parliament Square](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34704)* and *[Definite article before schools, colleges, and universities](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10020)* among many others. The best answer is to use whatever Dexter College says to use.

Answer (score -2):

'I am studying for my graduation in Dexter college' 
shall be good enough.
: **"The" comes if you add another sentence referring to the college again.** Supposing you were to say
"The Dexter college is located at Link road", for instance.

Comment: Barely good enough. At least in AmE, where you generally study for a test. *Working toward graduation* is more popular than studying for it. The definite article does not depend on a second reference but on the formal name of the school. Thus New College of Florida doesn't contain an article in its name, and you'd only use the article to distinguish the college from another  of the same name: *I mean the New College of Florida, not the one in Oxford*. (BTW, I am not the downvoter.)