# "I worked in a chemists" vs "I worked in a chemist's" vs "I worked in a chemist"?

Tags: grammatical-number, word-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Store names & possessive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14796/store-names-possessive)

What is the correct grammar for saying that I worked for a chemists (that is, a shop that sells medicine)?

Is it

> I worked in a chemist

or

> I worked in a chemists

or perhaps

> I worked in a chemist's

?

Had I been working for multiple different chemists, would it be correct to say

> I worked for chemists during my first two years of university

Comment: In America, the correct wording is, "I worked in a pharmacy" or "I worked in a drug store." :-) You can also say "I worked at ..." or "I worked for ..."

Comment: Jay: this is one of those differences between American English and British English. In the UK, the word chemist would be correct in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I worked in a chemist

Er, no: that would be rather uncomfortable for both of you!

> I worked in a chemists

*Chemists* is a plural noun, so *a chemists* can't be correct.

> I worked in a chemist's

This is an example of **ellipsis**: "I worked in a chemist's [shop]". Using the possessive is **entirely correct.**

> I worked for chemists during my first two years of university.

This is correct: *chemists* is a plural noun, indicating that you had more than one employer/mentor.

[Store names & possessive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14796/store-names-possessive) deals with people's names, not shop types.

Comment: Of course, the problem with the sentence _I worked for chemists during my first two years of university_ is that it's ambiguous, even in BrE. One of my friends worked for chemists when he was a student. But they were professors of Chemistry, not pharmacists or pharmacologists. There are also industrial chemists who are neither pharmacists nor pharmacologists. I wonder whether it's also idiomatic to say _I worked **at** a chemist's_ in BrE. Prepositions aren't equal across the Pond. Just curious because I don't know.

Comment: @B True; if we were definitely talking about chemists in a chemist's shop then *pharmacists* might be a better word. As regards *at*, it's not idiomatic but would not be misunderstood either. *In* implies some involvement; *at* implies a certain level of detachment, from simply not enjoying the job, all the way to the extent of being, say, an electrician working at the shop.

Comment: For many years the UK company Boots has used the tag line "Boots the chemist", but earlier they clearly use "Boots the chemists":  [Advertisement from 1911](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/ff/Boots_advert.jpg "wikimedia picture") and [old store fronts](http://www.boots-uk.com/About_Boots/Boots_Heritage.aspx "about Boots-uk.com"). Does that mean it used to be correct to say "I worked in a chemists" ?

Comment: @A Thank you for the explanation. I don't how many AmE speakers are able to explain preposition choices that way. I can come up with some definitely ad hoc explanations based on the meaning of the preposition, but some idiomatic usages just don't seem to fit the meaning well at all. Your explanation of this usage seems rational and not at all ad hoc.

Comment: @jamesj629 No. *Chemists* in "Boots the Chemists" is describing the people: there are more than one chemist. There was more than one [Boot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesse_Boot) as well, so it's not "Boot's".

Comment: A very old thread, but.. I wonder if the first example is really that bad. According to both: ["The Free Dictionary"](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/chemist%27s) and ["Oxford Dictionary"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/chemist) "chemist" and "chemist's" are both correct terms for a pharmacy. Granted, googling the exact sentence returns barely 5 pages of results with less than a half from UK and majority from countries where English is not an official language. I am confused. Is it possible that this changed over last five years?